# Facebook SDK - How to get a large profile image?

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an angular4 project and am using the Facebook SDKs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-facebook-sdk). When I try and receive a large image I get an error this is what the code looks like.

```
  getProfileData(apiResponse){
    this.fb.api('/me/picture?type=large,first_name,gender,email,verified')
      .then((userData:any)=>{
        console.log(userData);
```

> Object
>
> code: 100
>
> fbtrace_id: "DOrekxDNqTa"
>
> message: "(#100) For field 'picture': type must be one of the
>   following values: small, normal, album, large, square"
>
> type: "OAuthException"

As you can see I am passing a large image as part of the value of the parameter, but this doesn't work. Any ideas as to how to get this to work so that I can retrieve a large image from a profile would be great. Thanks!

Comment: _“As you can see I am passing a large image as a parameter”_ - No, you actually passed `large,first_name,gender,email,verified` as value for the `type` parameter.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks for pointing that you, I will make that edit.